# Bootstrap classes inside a defined class

Tags: css

Is there a way to put made classes inside a class?

e.g.

```
.my-upper-class{ .hidden-md, .hidden-sm, .hidden-lg}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with plain CSS, but with Sass, like so—

```
.hidden-sm {
  background: red;
}

.hidden-md {
  color: blue;
}

.hidden-lg {
  font-size: 1em;
}

.my-upper-class {
  @extend .hidden-sm;
  @extend .hidden-md;
  @extend .hidden-lg;
}
```

which outputs the final CSS as below, which is pretty much what you are looking for.

```
.hidden-sm, .my-upper-class {
  background: red;
}

.hidden-md, .my-upper-class {
  color: blue;
}

.hidden-lg, .my-upper-class {
  font-size: 1em;
}
```

Comment: Okay so I need to use Sass then sorry but I need to apply it on plain CSS.

Comment: No, not possible via plain CSS.